# Scrollbar keep showing next to my h1 in react

Tags: reactjs, sass

A scroll bar keeps showing next to my div in all of my project, I have tried to implement and `overflow: hidden` to its parent but it did not work. I have this problem in other parts of my project also.

[image]

```
import React from 'react'
import "./ContactMe.scss"

export default function ContactMe() {
    return (
        <div className='contactMe' id='contactMe'>
            <div className="left"></div>
            <div className="information">
                <div className="wrapper">
                    <h1>Let's discuss your Project!</h1>
                    <h2>Phone</h2>
                    <h2>email</h2>
                </div></div>
            <div className="form">.</div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

```
@import "../../global.scss";

.contactMe{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    


    .left{
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        width: 2rem;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: $text;

    }

    .information{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        flex: 0.4;

        .wrapper{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            margin-left: 2rem;
            
            h1{
                font-size: 5rem;
            }
            h2{

            }
        }
    }
    .form{
        flex: 0.6;
        background-color: brown;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you provide the global.scss file also?

Comment: This is because your h1 is overflowing from its wrapping div. You can increase the height of the wrapping div or add `overflow:hidden` property to it